# My Script wont log out

Tags: php, session, logout

```
// My session files starts the session 
require_once("./includes/session.php");


session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("location: login.php");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have started the session: `session_start();` before unsettling the session: `session_unset();`.